# How to exclude rows in one dataframe column from another dataframe

Tags: pandas

[image]

I tried the code snippet below but that results in a new two columns Datframe.

```
df_foo.join(df_bar, on="id", who="left")
```

Comment: How about `df1[~df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])]` ? or `df1.merge(df2,on='id',how='outer', suffixes=('','_'),indicator=True).query('_merge == "left_only"')`

Comment: Or just `reindex`: `df_foo.merge(df_bar, on="id", how="left", suffixes=('', '_y')).reindex(columns=df_foo.columns)`